# How to paste(using keyboard simulation) what's currently in clipboard on nextjs ubuntu ec2 instance using selenium?

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, next.js, copy-paste

I am trying to copy a text using a npm package called "copy-paste" and to paste the content using selenium keyboard simulation on nextjs ubuntu ec2 instance.

When I run below code from the local dev env, it works fine, but when I run it on ubuntu ec2 instance, it just sends "v" key instead of pasting the content in the clipboard.

I've tried all control, command, and meta key, but they all didn't work...

Plz help!

```
const { By, Key } = require("selenium-webdriver");
var ncp = require("copy-paste");

let resultElement = await driver.findElement(By.id("naver_id_login_anchor"));

  await resultElement.click();

  console.log("naver login button clicked");

  await driver.sleep(3000);

  const elem_id = await driver.findElement(By.id("id"));

  await elem_id.click();

  await driver.sleep(3000);

  await ncp.copy(id, () => console.log("id copied"));

  await driver.sleep(3000);

  await driver
    .actions()
    .keyDown(Key.META)
    .sendKeys("v")
    .keyUp(Key.META)
    .perform();

  await driver.sleep(3000);

  console.log(await elem_id.getAttribute("value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
el.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+ "v");
```

Comment: I've tried Key(It is Key instead of Keys in nodejs selenium).CONTROL(& COMMAND & META) + "v"  and Key.CONTROL(& COMMAND & META), "v". All didn't work...